# What percentage of the population were serfs by region/year?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, statistics

Where can I find statistics on the percentage of the population that were serfs, ideally broken down by country/region and by year? Even very rough estimates would be helpful, but unfortunately I've found even these to be hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, there is a distinct absence of any official counting being done, by anyone, until long after your period of interest - with the notable exception of the [Domesday Book](http://www.domesdaybook.net/home) commissioned by William I (The Conqueror) in 1086.

From my comment just now on the accepted answer to
[Are there equivalents of the Domesday Book for other (French or German) duchies?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/39335/are-there-equivalents-of-the-domesday-book-for-other-french-or-german-duchies)

> [Germany (or various principalities of the HRE if you prefer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Census_in_Germany) seems to have had Europe's first "*national*" census': Nuremberg in 1471; Brandenburg-Prussia starting in 1683 counted its rural population with the first state-wide census between 1719 and 1725. Also, [this](http://www.domesdaybook.net/home) might be a useful second link for the [Domesday Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesday_Book).

The accepted answer to [Did every medieval village in Europe have a manor, castle, or other type of lord's residence?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/53649/did-every-medieval-village-in-europe-have-a-manor-castle-or-other-type-of-lord/53680#53680) also bears on the current question.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom) cites Daniel D. McGarry, Medieval history and civilization (1976) p 242 for *"The Domesday Book showed that England comprised 12% freeholders, 35% serfs or villeins, 30% cotters and bordars, and 9% slaves."* which I think is an interesting data point.